# Compiling PHP 7.4.13 on CENTOS 7 gives error

Tags: php, compiler-errors, centos7

I am trying to upgrade PHP 7.3.9 to 7.4.13, while compiling it gives below error

```
-lcrypto -lcrypt  -o sapi/cli/php
/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libssl.so.38
/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.37
/bin/ld: ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: undefined reference to symbol 'X509_get_signature_nid@@libcrypto.so.10'
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
exiting with zero status
```

Here is my PHP compilation configuration

```
./configure \
       --prefix=/opt/php \
       --with-apxs2=/opt/apache/bin/apxs \
       --with-ldap=/opt/openldap \
       --enable-soap \
       --enable-sockets \
       --with-pgsql=/opt/php/pgsql \
       --with-pdo-pgsql=/opt/php/pgsql \
       --with-mysql \
       --with-pdo-mysql \
       --with-gd \
       --with-jpeg-dir \
       --with-png-dir \
       --with-zlib-dir \
       --with-freetype-dir \
       --enable-gd-native-ttf \
       --enable-pcntl \
       --with-openssl=/opt/libressl \
       --with-openssl-dir=/opt/libressl \
       --with-curl=/opt/curl \
       --enable-mbstring \
       --with-mcrypt \
       --with-config-file-path=/opt/php/etc \
       --with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/php/etc/php.d \
       --enable-zip \
       --with-xsl \
       --without-libzip
```

Can some please help how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the `-with-openssl=/opt/libressl` library to the latest version. That resolved my issue.